# write system call C - HDD Sequential or Random Access ?

Tags: random, system-calls, hard-drive, libc, sequential

I am looking for a solution to detect how's the write function access to the disk. I want to know if it is a sequential or random access. I thought about open the write system call on the libC and try to edit it and count if it is a random or seq access.. is it possible? how?

If there's another solution I would be thankful to know it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question probably has no sense today, because on today's disk even the hardware is handling disk sectors logically: two "consecutive" disk sectors are not *physically* near, because the [hard disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) controller is remapping them. Read also about [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA). Some controllers are even able to *re-order* pending disk requests.

BTW, an [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) does not have any *physical* geometry (for sectors), but does give the appearance of sector numbering.

In addition, the operating system kernel (notably Linux) is managing the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) so a `write` usually won't write directly the disk. See e.g. the [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) syscall.

At last, [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) is (on Linux and most Unixes) a [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), and happens inside the kernel. So you won't be able to change its behavior in your *libc*.

Read also about [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I already read about sync and I use it on some disk benchmarks at the moment. I did a LD_PRELOAD wrapper to filter the write/lseek functions.. maybe that's a good start for tracking random and sequential accesses. no?

Answer (score 3):

> I am looking for a solution to detect how's the write function access to the disk.

Since your question mentions libc, we could assume that you are running under some operating system, and not on a "bare metal" system, in which case the answer is that `write` function doesn't access disk *at all*. It merely asks the OS to (eventually) write the data to disk.